# Group by aggregate

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, group-by, distinct

This is my first touch with SQL Server and literally `I have no idea what I'm doing`.
Until today I only used MySQL, but lets cut to the chase.
I have a query which have joins.

```
SELECT locations.locationId, locations.code, locations.description,
       machines.RoutingCode, machines.FaNo, machines.nameBg 
FROM scanlog 
LEFT JOIN  locations ON locations.Barcode = scanlog.LineBarcode 
LEFT JOIN machines ON machines.barcode = scanlog.MachineBarcode
```

The problem:
I want to group the rows on `machines.RoutingCode` and `locations.code`.
I mean like in MySQL. If I have 20 entries with the same `routingCode` and same `code` and it will return to me only one row. So is there any way to do it here, or I should try something with DISTINCT?

Comment: The syntax is the same, yes, but I always get an error that some of the fields is not set in the aggregate function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this -

```
SELECT
      locationId = MAX(l.locationId)
    , l.Code
    , [description] = MAX(l.[description])
    , m.RoutingCode
    , FaNo = MAX(m.FaNo)
    , nameBg = MAX(m.nameBg)
FROM dbo.scanlog s
LEFT JOIN dbo.locations l ON l.BarCode = s.LineBarcode
LEFT JOIN dbo.machines m ON m.BarCode = s.MachineBarcode
GROUP BY 
       l.Code
     , m.RoutingCode
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the way, but I'm wondering why this happens? I have never met something like this in mysql.

Comment: You're welcome @David White. Sometimes query logic varies between `SQL Server` and `MySQL`. All tips you can find in `MSDN`.